# How to kill a specific Instance of a Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I know we can keep only one instance by

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
```

but I need that my app can create maximum two instances of certain activity not more than that.
I am using a chained **search** feature like image below
[image]

When Instance3 of the activity1 is created i want to destroy:-

1. Instance1 of activity1
2. Instance1 of activity2

Tried to used this to kill a specific activity but activity have same Pid for all processes in an app

```
 android.os.Process.killProcess( stack.getLast());
```

is there a way we can moderate which instances should be kept alive?

any help would be great thanks!

Comment: ever heard of finish() method.

Comment: @orvenito can you implement finish() method on a background activity from front activity? that also to a specific activity see image

Comment: Only the top activity is ever alive.  The backstack is conceptual.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede so back activities doesn't hamper ram or performance?

Comment: @phpdroid you mean killing an Activity when you are on other Activity?

Comment: @orvenito yes that only

Comment: @phpdroid They may use memory.  They shouldn't use CPU.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede ah great that solves my problem!

Comment: When I say "shouldn't", I mean an activity should cancel any background work when it is paused.  A misbehaving activity might use CPU in the backstack.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede can you Post that as an answer if other people have same doubt ?

Comment: check my answer if it is helpful

Comment: @phpdroid when the Instance3 of the activity1 is created, only instance1 of activity1 will be destroyed? Your requirement is "my app can create maximum two instances of certain activity", why you need to kill instance1 of activity2?

Comment: @AnhVu reduce memory consumption and reduce back key press to exit app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is the wrong architecture. For chained search you should only ever have a single instance of each `Activity`. You should flip between the different `Activity` instances by calling `startActivity()` and setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` in the `Intent` you use. Also add the data you want to display as "extras" in the `Intent`.

To be able to use the BACK button to back through the chain (no matter how long it is), each `Activity` should manage a stack that contains the data that it needs to recreate the page whenever the user backs into it. In `onCreate()` and in `onNewIntent()` the data (from the "extras") should be pushed onto the stack and displayed. You then override `onBackPressed()` and go back to the previous `Activity` by calling `startActivity()`, and setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` in the `Intent` you use. You also add an "extra" to the `Intent` that indicates the user wants to "go back". In `onBackPressed()` you should also discard the top element off the data stack of the `Activity` that is being left. This will ensure that the stack is correct when the user then backs into this `Activity`.

In `onNewIntent()` if the user just backed into the `Activity`, you just display the data that is already on top of the stack of managed data.

In this way, you only ever have one instance of each `Activity`, the user can chain all day through the set of activities and the BACK button always works and you don't have to worry about running out of memory.

Trying to accomplish this using `taskAffinity` or `Intent` flags or similar will not work. Don't waste your time. It is also bad programming style.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your answer and had implement same in my other project but here there are Two types of searchs (Displays) which forced me to use two different activities.

Comment: Yes. 2 different activities is fine. A->B->A->B->A->B etc. But you should have only 1 instance of each and each manages its own stack.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to remove entries 1 and 2 from the backstack when you create the 5th one, but leave the 3rd and 4th. Unfortunately, the backstack doesn't work that way, you can only manipulate it from the top. You have the option of clearing all the activities except the last one if you set the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, you will have an empty task only with the just started activity.

If I were you, I wouldn't worry about memory consumption by the old activities though. As long as you stop the resource-consuming processes in your activities when they leave the screen and don't hold the references to them so they can be garbage collected, Android can manage the memory itself fine. What you should think about is whether it makes sense for the user to come back to the old activities if he presses back. If yes, then leave them, if no, then don't.

In case you want to kill all your activities on the back button press, there is an `Activity.finishAffinity()` method. Just override the `onBackPressed` method to call it.

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` giving problem for my shared element transition

Comment: @phpdroid That's why it's better to simply implement the activity lifecycle correctly and leave the rest to the OS.

Comment: I know but that will kill my instance2 also that's the issue

Comment: and the much better option is to call `finish()` after `startActivity()`

Comment: @phpdroid Now I can't understand what you are trying to do. If you want to exit the app, then you finish all the activities. If you want to only kill activities from the bottom of the backstack, that can't be done. If you are worried about the resources, Android can manage that.

Comment: please, can you check answer posted by Anh Vu ?

Comment: @phpdroid Won't work. When the activity is off the screen, it won't receive any events since it unregisters in `onStop`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little hack with EventBus or BroadcastReceiver or some other Bus. Check my following code for my idea. For this app, I will keep maximum 2 instances of `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int count = 0;

int id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    count ++;
    id = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID", 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", count);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new Event(count));
}

@Subscribe
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    if (id < (event.getID() - 2)) {//put your logic code to finish the activity here
        Log.i("MainActivity", id + " is killed ");
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

you can do this bro,

declare one Activity object like this

```
public static Activity factivity;
    onCreate()
    {
        factivity = this;
    }
```

now you can use that object to kill that specific activity on another activity like this:

```
onCreate()
{
    FirstActivity.factivity.finish();
}
```

Comment: You should NEVER do this. Keeping a static reference to an Activity prevents that instance from being garbage collected, which means a memory leak.

Comment: yes above comment is correct that y i was saving `Context` in a stack but am not able to call `stack.getLast().finish();`

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti what do you suggest to do?

Comment: You need to work your way around with intent flags, unfortunately. They are not always perfectly clear, but they are what the platform has to offer when it comes to managing the stack. In certain situations, you can work with `taskAffinity`, for instance.
Overall, the static instance may solve this issue, but it opens a whole new can of worms.